# Selenium python: How to avoid access denied

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to click on a link when crawling a website to read the data there. When I click on the link the page "Access denied" opens. Is there a possibility to pass over this?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class GetdatagalaxusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getdatagalaxus'
    allowed_domains = ['www.galaxus.ch']
    start_urls = ['https://www.galaxus.ch']

    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.galaxus.ch/de/Wiki/2736'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Applications/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get(url)
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/aside/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/a').click()
        sleep(10)
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: add the code error if u want some help

Comment: What are you trying to open? Your locator opens links to different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered passing the request headers?

At present the implicit start_requests() method is being called without header info.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html?highlight=request%20headers